# Has a system upgrade ever really destroyed data?

Tags: backup, software-update

Whenever you are upgrading your system, the first step is to back up important data, in case something goes wrong. However, when I am thinking about it, what could possibly realistically go wrong on a system upgrade?

All I can think of is the OS not booting, or some programs not working. But that won't affect data (especially if `/home` would be on another partition). A live distro can easily reach your data again then.

It would take considerable effort and time to actually destroy the data beyond repair, so I was wondering, what is the real risk of not backing up before an upgrade? Has there been real-world examples of (user) data being fried after a upgrade?

Final note: we do minor updates all the time, without backing up, why would that then not be a problem?

Comment: *we do minor updates all the time, without backing up*... Really? That means you're not regularly and frequently backing up your data. Ransomware is successful because, sadly, you're not alone.

Comment: I only just spotted the 'final note'. That really is the wrong way to think of things. I do minor backups constantly, once an hour locally & once a day off-site [plus cloud-sync to all my personal devices with every single data-change of things like contacts, keychains, even what page I'm on in my current book, movie or work document]... whether I'm actually 'updating' anything or not. The modern adage is **"Any data not stored in at least three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary".**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**
It happened with Microsoft only last year.

Microsoft released a Win10 update last year that erased user's documents. Best source I can find right now is - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-10-1809-update-deleted-all-files-from/ff608374-2686-4a08-a4c2-caa4caa6d4e1

Will try to update later, real life is calling right now... ;)

*Edit*

I found the original blog from Microsoft - [Updated version of Windows 10 October 2018 Update released to Windows Insiders](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/10/09/updated-version-of-windows-10-october-2018-update-released-to-windows-insiders/)

Answer (score 0):

> [W]e do minor updates all the time, without backing up, why would that then not be a problem?

A major update typically has breaking changes that cannot (easily) be reversed, whereas a minor update tries to maintain compatibility and doesn't have breaking changes.  This is why minor updates are generally considered safer.

> [W]hat is the real risk of not backing up before an upgrade?

If there is a breaking change or database migration without a way to go back "down" and you do not have a backup, you are forced to use a newer version of the software that may have serious unwanted regressions.

> Has a system upgrade ever really destroyed data?
>   
>   Has there been real-world examples of (user) data being fried after a upgrade?

Yes, and quite recently, too:

- [Windows 10 October 2018 Update is deleting user data](https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-october-2018-update-seems-be-deleting-users-data)

  - > [I have just updated my windows using the October update (10, version 1809) it deleted all my files of 23 years in amount of 220gb.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/windows-10-october-2018-update-version-1809/1a924008-ddba-48db-a96f-7b4bfef9039a)
  - > [So after updating I discovered that my documents, pictures, music, videos are gone.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/9l2v3z/windows_1809_update_wiped_my_documents/)

Example of unwanted breaking changes:

- [WordPress Gutenberg](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg/) – rated 1.9 of 5 stars

  [image: Ratings of WordPress plugin Gutenberg as of 05 May 2019] (ratings as of 05 May 2019)

  - > [The Gutenberg 4.5.1 update has completely broken the visual editor on my site. In fact, all of the text and images have just… disappeared. I cannot copy and paste any new text on a given page.](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/gutenberg-4-5-1-a-major-and-possibly-fatal-fail-for-wordpress-moving-forward/)

Example involving an irreversable migration by a web service:

- [Myspace deleted 12 years’ worth of music in a botched server migration](https://www.theverge.com/2019/3/18/18271023/myspace-music-videos-deleted-2003-2015-server-migration)

Comment: Thanks. My question was mainly about user-data though. Whatever files are stored in a photo dir, or my LibreOffice files for example.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answers: A minor update can also break the operating
system.

Updating a driver is counted as minor, but if it installs the wrong driver,
or the right driver has a problem with your setup, then that device might
malfunction. If the device is essential for booting, or for your work,
then you are in trouble.

In my book, there are no minor updates. Each update is dangerous.
I never do any update without taking backups, because I don't feel lucky.

Comment: "If the device is essential for booting, or for your work, then you are in trouble." yes, but would it destroy data? A live OS could still get to the data, I'd say.

Comment: We are getting into rare scenarios, but think about the trouble that a bad disk driver can cause, or an encrypted file becoming undecryptable etc. I believe in better safe than sorry.

Comment: I understand that it *can* break the OS, but has it ever, in the real world, actually happened?